# without entering username and password my application is logging

Tags: android

i have created a login page when i enter username and password(if both are equal) it is used to login but the username and password are left blank and when i click on login button on emulator its shows the login succesful
it should not login when the username and password are left balnk

```
 @Override
         public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.main);

     txtUserName=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.txtUname);
     txtPassword=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.txtPwd);
     btnLogin=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
     btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {            

                    if((txtUserName.getText().toString()).equals(txtPassword.getText().toString())){
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), SaveData.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 1);
                    Toast.makeText(LoginappActivity.this, "Login Successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else{
                    Toast.makeText(LoginappActivity.this, "Invalid Login",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                    }
               }
           });
 }           
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add condition   `txtUserName.getText().toString().length() > 0` with `&& operator` in `if`

```
if((txtUserName.getText().toString().length() > 0) && (txtUserName.getText().toString()).equals(txtPassword.getText().toString())){
       Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), SaveData.class);
       startActivityForResult(myIntent, 1);
       Toast.makeText(LoginappActivity.this, "Login Successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       } else{
          Toast.makeText(LoginappActivity.this, "Invalid Login",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
          }
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

Its because blank username and password is also equal. You need to check if the user does not enter any value then prompt for it. More appropriately, use `TextUtils.isEmpty` to do this job.

```
public void onClick(View v) { 
   String username = txtUserName.getText().toString();
   String password = txtPassword.getText().toString();

   if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(username) && username.equals(password)){

          //do your stuff
   }
}
```

Comment: Well you don't need to check if both are empty.. since you are comparing if they are equal after..

Answer (score 2):

try some validation first that whether any one field is blank or not
you validated code is

```
 btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View v) {            

                        if(txtUserName.getText().toString()).equals("")){
                             //Show Message
                        }else if(txtPassword.getText().toString().equals("")){
                             //Show Message
                        }else if(!(txtUserName.getText().toString()).equals(txtPassword.getText().toString())){
                           Toast.makeText(LoginappActivity.this, "Invalid Login",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                        }else{
                            Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), SaveData.class);
                            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 1);
                            Toast.makeText(LoginappActivity.this, "Login Successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                   }
               });
```

Answer (score 1):

you just check both are equal and both are blank so if condition is true...

so you should check both field is empty or not ...

**Like...**

```
String strName = txtUserName.getText().toString();
String strPass = txtPwd.getText().toString();


     if(strName!=null&&strName.trim().length!=0&&strPass!=null && strPass.trim().length!=0){

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), SaveData.class);
    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 1);
    Toast.makeText(LoginappActivity.this, "Login Successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

  }else{
                Toast.makeText(LoginappActivity.this, "input your name and password",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

That happens because `""` is equal to `""` (empty string)

You might want to add this

```
[...]
if(txtUserName.getText().toString().length() > 0 && (txtUserName.getText().toString()).equals(txtPassword.getText().toString()))
[...]
```